# How to properly runserver on different settings for Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a basic django rest API. I want to separate some of my settings for dev and prod just for organizational purposes. I'm also just learning about separating environments. I've read a few things, but I can't seem to get it working the way I want it to.

The hierarchy looks like this:

```
- djangorest
  - api
    - __init__.py
    - models.py
    - views.py
    - urls.py
    - etc..
  - djangorest
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
```

Right now, when I run the server, I do a simple:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

That command reads the settings from settings.py and runs it appropriately but I've looked around on how to separate the settings into prod vs dev and it doesn't work right.

I want to be able to have:

```
commonsettings.py
dev.py
prod.py
```

In commonsettings, it'll just have whatever's in both dev and prod. I've tried running:

```
python3 manage.py runserver --settings=settings.dev
```

But it gives me an error saying there is no module named 'setting'.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Try `python3 manage.py runserver --settings=djangorest.dev` instead.

Comment: Or `djangorest.settings.dev`, if the settings files are in a settings directory.

Comment: https://medium.com/wemake-services/managing-djangos-settings-e2b7f496120d

Answer (score 14):

For example I open SQL log in dev settings

1. My file structure:
   create settings folder and mv original settings.py to settings/defaults.py
   [image]
2. load defaults in **init**.py

```py
# proj/proj/settings/__init__.py

from .defaults import *
```

3. Edit dev.py

```py
# proj/proj/settings/dev.py

from .defaults import *
DEBUG = True

# print sql to the console
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    },
}
```

4. run in the python env

```
./manage.py runserver --settings proj.settings.dev
```

[image]

*Django 2.1.7 | Mac*

Comment: What is the purpose of the import within __init__.py?

Comment: To set the folder as a module

Answer (score 9):

Create a folder called config

```
config/
    commonsettings.py
    dev.py
    prod.py
```

make sure that in dev.py and prod.py you import everything from commonsettings.py like this:

```
from .commonsettings import *
```

then if you want to run the dev.py settings:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=config.dev
```

if you want to run prod.py:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=config.prod
```

NOTE:

For more readable files many developers call their settings files: local.py (for the local settings) production.py (for the production settings) and base.py (the common settings for both)

Personally I place my setting files in:

```
config/
    settings/
        base.py
        local.py
        production.py
        test.py (For tests)
```

Comment: there is no need for __init__.py file?

Answer (score 4):

This solution works without extra arguments, and without having to replace/delete files across environments.

### Make settings.py decide which file to load

Let's assume your Django project is named MyDjangoApp.

Create the `config/` dir in your Django project's root dir, and one `.py` file per environment, e.g. like this:

```
config/
  local.py
  dev.py
  prod.py
MyDjangoApp/
  settings.py
```

There is no logical limit to the number of environments, I just added the three I usually have.

Then, inside `MyDjangoApp/settings.py` we can add the logic to choose which settings file to load.

```
"""
Django settings for MyDjangoApp project.
"""

import os

# Begin: Custom per-env settings
import socket
# Use the appropriate logic to understand "where" we're running
HOST = socket.gethostname() 
configs = {
    'localhost': 'local', # replace 'localhost' with whatever your machine name is
    'dev.mysite.com': 'dev',
    'www.mysite.com': 'production',
}

config = 'config.{}'.format(configs[HOST])

settings_module = __import__(config, globals(), locals(), ['MyDjangoApp', ])

try:
    for setting in dir(settings_module):
        # Only fully-uppercase variables are supposed to be settings
        if setting == setting.upper():
            locals()[setting] = getattr(settings_module, setting)
except Exception:
    # you may ignore this exception, the print() is for debugging purposes 
    print(Exception)

# End: Custom per-env settings

# ... the rest of the common settings go here
```

**Please note:** this logic chooses the settings file to load based on the *hostname* of the server which is running the Django app. It's just an example- you can implement any other logic that works for you.

### Change only what's needed

The good news is, settings.py can still hold the vast majority of your settings, and the files inside `config/` just need to contain the settings that **change across your environments**, e.g.:

- DATABASES
- DEBUG
- ADMINS
- LOGGING

### Avoid --settings in the commandline

You can set the Django settings as a shell environment variable, like this:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=MyDjangoApp.settings
```

The best place to do this is in a `.sh` file; usually I create a file named `env.sh` file in the root dir of the Django project, and run it (once) just after activating the virtualenv.

**File /env.sh contents**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=MyDjangoApp.settings
```

To run it from Terminal (Bash, or git-scm Bash on Windows):

```
. env.sh
```

Then you can use `./manage.py runserver` to start the Django server wherever you are.

Reference: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#DevelopmentMachineDependantSettingsConfiguration

Comment: is there anything in specific wrong with using the settings flag in command line?

Comment: No. I avoid it for two reasons: the first one is portability (same command across environments), second one is that I don't want to save the environment in the shell history.

Answer (score 2):

Put all your common configurations in the **commonsettings**.**py** file.

add following the line into the **__init__.py** file in the **settings** directory

```
from commonsettings import *
```

This makes every configuration in the **commonsettings** file available in all other files in the settings folder

start your server with

```
python3 manage.py runserver --settings=djangorest.settings.dev
```

Answer (score 1):

> Project Hierarchy will be

```
- djangorest
  - api
    - __init__.py
    - models.py
    - views.py
    - urls.py
    - etc..
  - djangorest
    - settings           (folder)
    - commonsettings.py
    - dev.py
    - prod.py
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
```

After This run following commands before **python manage.py runserver**

> export PYTHONPATH=$PWD
>
> export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djangorest.settings.dev
>
> and Finally **python manage.py runserver**

Answer (score 0):

Replace settings.py with dev.py on dev server  and prod.py on production server.

now in init.py files write code

```
try:
    print("Trying import production.py settings...")
    from .prod import *
except ImportError:
    print("Trying import development.py settings...")
    from .dev import *
```

it find prod.py in production server and import it. On dev server it not find and prod.py and import dev.py

then you don't need to specify configuration file name while running runserver command.

Answer (score 0):

What I've always done is on the local env create a file called `local_settings.py` that can have it's own database settings, static path and so on and at the end of the settings file include this

```
try:
    from local_settings import *#
except:
    pass
```

so on the server I always make sure not to import the local_settings and it separates the two nicely.