# Dockerized Django REST Application and PostgreSQL DB

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

Is there any way that I do not need to change my settings.py file every time i decide to run my application ? What I mean is this:

-Every time I want to run dockerized application with docker-compose my settings.py file looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'agent_technologies_db',
        'USER': 'stefan_radonjic',
        'PASSWORD': 'cepajecar995',
        'HOST': 'db', 
        'PORT': '',
        }
}
```

-And every time i want to run my application on my local machine my settings.py looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'agent_technologies_db',
        'USER': 'stefan_radonjic',
        'PASSWORD': 'cepajecar995',
        'HOST': 'localhost', 
        'PORT': '',
        }
}
```

Is there any way around this?

Here is what my docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=stefan_radonjic
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=cepajecar995
      - POSTGRES_DB=agent_technologies_db
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: 
      - .:/agent-technologies
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49237289/719247

Comment: This link has helped! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: use two separate settings files.

When running on local machine, use `settings.py`.

When running in Docker, use `settings-docker.py` (or whatever the name is), and bind mount this file into the container as `settings.py`. This way, your application inside the container will see only the `settings.py` file as expected.

Simply modify your docker-compose.yml file like this (make sure to use the correct path):

```
volumes: 
  - .:/agent-technologies
  - settings-docker.py:/app/settings.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by following the solution provided on the following link:

[How to properly runserver on different settings for Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235486/how-to-properly-runserver-on-different-settings-for-django/49237289#49237289)